# How does one change the path to the .emacs directory?

Tags: emacs

I'd like to move the place that emacs looks for the init file.

(The reason is: I use emacs on 3 different computers, and would like the init file in, e.g., dropbox, so that each of the 3 computers has the same init file.)

Comment: You could create a one-liner `.emacs` or `init.el` that loads your dropbox init file, and store them in the usual locations on each computer.  You could also modify `startup.el` and build Emacs using your modified `startup.el`, which is what I do -- i.e., I programmatically test for what flavor of OS and/or computer and/or screen dimensions, and Emacs looks for my custom init.el in the location that varies from computer to computer.  I have a countdown timer that also gives me a few seconds to start with no user configuration, or the full monty.

Comment: Perfect! I did this, and it is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!